# Connecting a rails application from local machine to live database server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to connect my rails application from ubuntu local machine to live database server. I got a project where schema.rb and migration file are very messy.I want to connect it with live database. Here database is mysql. Is it possible to connect with live server?

Comment: Are you sure you want to connect your local development environment to the production database? you may lose your data by just "trying". In all cases, it's possible if the database sever has a URL or dedicated IP, and the security policy of the database server allows remote connections.

Comment: It can help you http://cobwwweb.com/connect-to-a-remote-mysql-database-in-rails